# in laravel how to convert passed value one line text in to group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

how to convert on line text in to group

**like**

```
 Be very careful when 
echoing content that is
 supplied by users of
  your application
```

**present it showing like this**

```
 Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application
```

**my code**

```
<div ><font size="1"><p >{{$view->text}} </p></font></div>
```

Comment: you should be able to do that with css. Give your div tag a class name then set the width of div.

Comment: You need to convert new lines to HTML line breaks. See `nl2br`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php You also should update your code, `font` is an old element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font `deprecated in HTML 4.01, at the same time as all elements related to styling only, then obsoleted in HTML5.`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing newline characters from the string:

```
<div><font size="1"><p>{{ str_replace("\n", "", $view->text) }}</p></font></div>
```

Comment: See @bilpor's comment, you likely need to set the width of the containing element so it doesn't wrap.

Answer (score 0):

your text have styles (color and sentences in lines) you may use ​`WYSIWYG` editor to store you text in the database some thing like that

```
$description = $request->input('description');
$dom = new \DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($description, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);    
$description = $dom->saveHTML();

$post = new Post;
$post->description = $description;
$post->save();
```

after that, you can simply display it like that in your blade

```
{!! $description !!}
```